# PI 3 OrCAD schematics

Tags: electronics

I am looking for schematics of the raspberry PI 3 suitable for use with [OrCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OrCAD).

Comment: May I ask why? Are you planning on modifying them yourself, or is it just for educational purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Official documentation and schematics for the Raspberry Pi is available at the [Raspberry Pi Foundation's Webpage](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/README.md). However, as of today and to my knowledge, the full schematics for the Pi3 are not released. I am also not aware of any published reverse engineered schematics of any kind (not judging the ethical or legal ramifications of such actions). Asking for a specific format on the other hand is even more out of line (if you ask me).